# Android using LocalBroadcastManager inside android Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-context, android-broadcast

I am trying to use the LocalBroadcastManager inside an android service.

```
public class WebSocketService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "WebSocketService";
    private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;

    public WebSocketService() {
        connectWebSocket();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void connectWebSocket() {
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI("wss://echo.websocket.org");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }


        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Websocket Opened");
                mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Websocket Received: " + message);

                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("custom-event");
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Websocket closed: " + reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Websocket error");
            }
        };
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        mWebSocketClient.send(message);
    }
}
```

The main Activity where the websocket gets created.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebSocketService webSocketService;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webSocketService = new WebSocketService();
    }

    public void send(View view) {
        webSocketService.sendMessage("socket message");
    }
}
```

and its xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="send"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="166dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="288dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The above does no compile with exception

After changing `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);` to 
`LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);`

I get the error
`Error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`

My question is whether its possible to pass the context while creating

```
mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
}
```

such that the LocalBroadcastManager can be used or not?

The question in general is, is it possible to get the applicationContext inside an annoymous namespace.

Comment: How are you starting this `WebSocketService`? add code

Comment: @ADM added code that starts websocket, The question is general is can we get applicationContext inside an annoymous method of any service/activity class?

Comment: You can have but you should not.. This leads to memory leak and Null pointer Exception like in this case ..

Comment: @ADM  am using DI that I have not included as the question would be really big then, this is for representation purpose, the main problem is how to get the pplicationContext inside an annoymous method of any service/activity class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an outerScope **this** inside an annoymous method / inner class of any java class you can either call **WebSocketService.this**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(WebSocketService.this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

or declare a private helper method for the same

```
private WebSocketService getOuterWebSocketService() {
  return this;
}
```

Now you can use this method inside **onMessage** as below

```
@Override
public void onMessage(String message) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Websocket Received: " + message);
  Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("custom-event");
  broadcastIntent.putExtra("message", message);             
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getOuterWebSocketService()).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```